# MATLAB bar() error: 'Unrecognized option "var" with custom variable names

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm writing longer script for plotting some bar plots in Matlab. I want to set my own colors of the bars when a proper condition is met. I have 30 bars in one plot. That's the general background, I won't paste here this long code, instead of I created shorter code only to illustrate one particular problem I'm struggling with. For some reason bar() function in MATLAB doesn't allow to use custom variables to indicate which plot needs to be, for example in this case, re-colored.

Here's the sample script that I prepared:

```
cond_1 = 10;
cond_2 = 8;
i = 1;

cond_SD_1 = 2;
cond_SD_2 = 3;

z = [cond_1, cond_2];
zz = [cond_SD_1, cond_SD_2];


hold on

newName=sprintf('cond_%d',i); 

title(newName);

bar(1, cond_1, 'FaceColor', 'Red','LineWidth',2)   
bar(2, newName, 'FaceColor', 'Blue','LineWidth',2)

errorbar(z,zz,'color',[.44 .44 .44],'linestyle','none','linewidth',2), grid on, grid minor, box off,         
hold off
```

So let's say that we want to have two bars only, like in the example above. And we need to use custom variable to tell `bar()` which bar we want to change. We created the variable in this line `(newName=sprintf('cond_%d',i);)` - it gave as a char of `cond_1`. When we call `bar()` like that `bar(1, cond_1, 'FaceColor', 'Red','LineWidth',2)` everything works fine, but when we want to use `bar(2, newName, 'FaceColor', 'Blue','LineWidth',2)` it gives an error `Unrecognized option "cond_1".`. I also added there `title()` function, which doesn't have this problem and understands char variables perfectly. `title(newName);` with our custom variable name `newName` is set correctly as a title. I used this method several times before, and it seems that this problem occurs only with `bar()` function. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help!
BM

Comment: You seem to be confusing a _variable_ with its _name_. `cond_1` works because it's a variable containing a _numeric array_ (in this case a single number), as `bar` expects. `newName` doesn't work because it's a variable containing a _char vector_ (which is the name of another variable). Not sure how to solve your use because I don't quite get what you want to do

Comment: why dont you save your variables in arrays in general, so you can access the needed values through indexing. Additionally, (perhaps only my opinion) I dont recommend you to use bar plots, as they give a wrong impression of distributions (like filling up), rather use boxplots or scatterplots

Comment: @Luis Mendo Yes, I'm aware of that. newName is a char (as I wrote in my question). I would like to use the custom variable with custom name to put it in bar() instead of just writing 'cond_1'. As I wrote in the beginning: I have a much bigger script with 30 bars in one plot, and I want to color them with different colors when a proper condition is met (I have 'for' loop and then 'if' statement: that's why I need to have this possibility to create the variable with a proper name which will correspond to existing bar). I hope I was more clear now.

Comment: If you want to dynamically choose one variable or anoother, they [should not](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) be different variables; they should be for example cells in a cell array, which you can dynamicall index into

Comment: @Irreducible For some simple "checking" the barplots are more way simpler than boxplots, which I also of course use in my work. For now I want to plot my data on simple barplots. I don't understand the part about "arrays in general" - then I would have an char array or array of strings, which will also do not work with bar().

Comment: @Luis Mendo Even if this will be for example a structure with one column of chars, then it would not work `bar(2, struct(1).example, 'FaceColor', 'Blue','LineWidth',2)`. How you would make it work? It's the same problem: the struct(1).example or samplecellarray{1} will be a char, and it will not work with bar().

Comment: For structs you could use dynamic field names to retrieve the _contents_ of a field (as opposed to its _name_); see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)

Comment: I would highly disagree that barplots are easier as they give you a false impression, however this is up to you. I meant that you collect your data in an array as in the answer by Luis, in his case all the data is in the array `z` (a 1 by 10 array) and you access the data by indexing (in your case you would use the index `i`)

Comment: @Luis Mendo It doesn't solve the problem. As we can read: (1) "when evaluated, returns a character vector or (...) a string scalar; (2) "dynamic field name can return either a character vector or a string scalar". So once again: we end with char or a string, which doesn't work with bar(). That's not a solution.

Comment: @Irreducible I cannot agree with you. Bar plots are the easiest plots we can imagine, every person understands what "mean" means and what they show. With box plots it's not that easy, people do not understand what's first, third quartile, what's median and it's harder to read in general. I can't use indexing - as I wrote before, I need to choose the "name" when the proper condition is met.

Comment: The _field name_ is a string or char vector. Its _contents_ can be anything. Try `a.b = [1 2 3]; fieldname = 'b'; a.(fieldname)`

Comment: @BloodyMary if you want to show the mean and variance then only show the mean and variance and no bar which has no statistical information. Keep in mind that by only showing this two parameters you are implying a normal distribution!!! Nevertheless this is a question of taste and should not be discussed here. In the same way you initialise your name variables and index them ( in your case the index is at the end of the name) you can assign your values to a vector and access them. This is easier than using names. I see you finally understood it by accepting the answer

Comment: @Irreducible Why/how does specifying only the mean and the variance imply a normal distribution?

Comment: you are implying a certain symmetry and stating that the distribution is parametric. ( i should have said this instead of normal), in the situation when it is skewed or has multiple maxima, mean and variance alone will be misleading

Comment: @Luis Mendo Have you read that from my comment? I didn't say anything like that. I only said that for most of the people (not PhD's in Telecommunication Engineering :) reading bar plot is easier than reading box plot. Sometimes reading box plot is even not possible, because of the lack of knowledge. And even if someone is familiar with all of the terms, it's still easier to somehow evaluate bar plot. Can you agree with me on that?

Comment: @BloodyMary Did you mean to respond to Irreducible? I didn't say anything about bar vs box plots

Comment: @Luis Mendo Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't see your conversation with Irreducible, I thought that you're writing to me.

Comment: If you want an information about the distribution of your data ( density, location and skeweness) without any assumption if it is parametric or not a boxplot is the way to go or a scatter plot which can be overlayed by a mean and the variance. A bar blot in regards of mean and variance makes no sense as the mean is no glass which is filled up. Just put a marker like a circle at the mean value. But hey a free world. Do what you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use variable names like `cond_1` and `cond_2`. Instead, your array `z` is all you need. `z(i)` is the element you want to color differently. Let’s take a slightly larger dat set as example:

```
z = 9*rand(1,10) + 9;
zz = 2*rand(1,10) + 1;
k = find(z>14) % the bars to color red
x = 1:10;

hold on
bar(x,z, 'FaceColor', 'Blue','LineWidth',2)   
bar(x(k),z(k), 'FaceColor', 'Red','LineWidth',2)
errorbar(x,z,zz, 'color',[.44 .44 .44],'linestyle','none','linewidth',2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this post. That is something that I haven't think about and that totally solves my problem. Thanks for this great and simple advice!